# How to sort column of table by value of another table row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are two tables:

1. columns

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | col1 |
| 2 | col2 |

2. user_settings

| id | name | params |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | { "columns": [ {"col_id": 1, "place": 2}, {"col_id": 2, "place": 1} ], "anotherParam": "" } |
| 2 | user2 | { "columns": [ {"col_id": 1, "place": 2}, {"col_id": 2, "place": 1} ], "anotherParam": "" } |

I want to get all columns like:

```
@columns = Column.all
```

And then sort it by value of params for current user from user_settings table based on "col_id" = columns.id. @columns at end must be Column::ActiveRecord_Relation.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me the best strategy in such cases is to forget about ActiveRecord for the moment, build the proper solution in raw SQL and when you have everything in place "migrate" it to the AR query API.

Your `params` column for `user_settings` table looks like JSON data to me - this means the solution actually depends on the database you use (because different databases - and sometimes even different versions of the same one - provide different interfaces to the json data).

But in general the solution is as follows: "unpack" json array into a recordset, join it to other data you need and then everything else is kinda straightforward...

For example, in PostgreSQL it might look like this:

```
select c.*
from
  columns c,
  user_settings s,
  jsonb_to_recordset(s.params->'columns') as params(col_id integer, place integer)
where c.id = params.col_id and s.id = 1
order by params.place
;
```

Where `jsonb_to_recordset` transforms the json array into a recordset, then this recordset is joined with the `columns` table based on your criteria and then ordering got applied.

Here is the whole solution with your sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ffaa19/1

UPD. Oops. You mentioned AR_Relation as the desired output. It might be a bit trickier (`find_by_sql` returns an array). Could you please add wider context - why getting the AR relation is crucial in this case?

UPD2. Updated the answer based on the changed data sample.

Comment: AR relation as output because I use @columns variable in view next.

Database - postgres, yes.

Comment: Do you do anything more complicated in a view than just iterating over your `@columns` and rendering them? If not then the array will behave in quite the same way AR relation does...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can use array too. Thanks, but can you help with query again? On fact my params look like: { "columns": [ {"col_id": 1, "place": 2}, {"col_id": 2, "place": 1} ] } . How to modify your example for this?

Comment: Could you update the question with the correct data sample, please?

Comment: @aaltw I updated the answer based on your updated data sample.